# Entity with many to many and many to one serialization with spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a rest api for an app like Trello. I have a set of entities that need to be loaded in a certain way when the board is loaded.

The entity of the **board:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "boards")
public class Board {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "board_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "last_edit")
  private Timestamp lastEdit;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "boards")
  private List<User> users;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board")
  private List<Role> roles;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board")
  private List<BoardList> lists;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the **user:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "usr_password", nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "preferences")
  private String preferences;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taskDoer")
  private List<Task> tasks;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Comment> comments;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "board_users",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
  )
  private List<Board> boards;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "user_roles",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  )
  private List<Role> roles;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the **role:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "role_id")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
  private Board board;

  @Column(name = "role_name")
  private String roleName;

  @Column(name = "role_permissions")
  private String rolePermissions;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
  private List<User> users;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the list in the **board:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "lists")
public class BoardList {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "list_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "list_position")
  private Integer listPosition;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "board_id")
  private Board board;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "list")
  private List<Task> tasks;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the **Task** in the list:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "task_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "task_text")
  private String taskText;

  @Column(name = "task_position")
  private Integer taskPosition;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "list_id")
  private BoardList list;

  @Column(name = "due_date")
  private Date dueDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "task_doer_id")
  private User taskDoer;

  @Column(name = "task_preferences")
  private String taskPreferences;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
  private List<Comment> comments;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "task_labels",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id")
  )
  private List<Label> labels;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the **board:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "labels")
public class Label {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "label_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "label_info")
  private String info;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "labels")
  private List<Task> tasks;
  //other methods
}
```

The entity of the **comment** on the task:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "comment_id")
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
  private Task task;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "comment_text")
  private String text;

  @Column(name = "comment_date")
  private Timestamp commentDate;
  //other methods
}
```

I have created a `JpaRespoitory` for each entity.
The bottom line is that when loading the board, I have to load the users related to the board, but only the username and id. Then roles for each of these users, but only those that relate to the board. The main difficulty lies in the fact that when loading board lists, I also have to load tasks with labels related to them (again without a list of tasks inside), as well as comments for each task, and the user in them should also contain only id and username.
I think you need to use DTO for this, but I don't know how to use them correctly in this case.
[Relation diagram of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE3cE.png)
I also attach a relationship diagram of my database.

I tried using `NamedEntityGraph`, but it still didn't work.